# how to group identical latitude and longitudes to display multiple locations in tableau

Tags: geolocation, visualization, data-visualization, geospatial, tableau-api

So I have a list of LATs and LONGs with venues in a csv file. Let's say they look like this:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+--+
| latitude | longitude | venue         | address     |  |
+----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+--+
| 23.123   | 44.32123  | music concert | 123 fake st |  |
+----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+--+
| 23.123   | 44.32123  | football      | 123 fake st |  |
+----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+--+
| 33.2342  | 41.2343   | theatre       | 22 red st   |  |
+----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+--+
| 33.2342  | 41.2343   | comedy        | 22 red st   |  |
+----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+--+
```

The goal is to have 2 single points in tableau, but when the user clicks on a point you can see the details or hover text showing 2 distinct venues for each point. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it have to be hover text? My first suggestion is to do this in a dashboard, use and use a filter action to show the detail.

Comment: yep that's what i'm doing now. the hover text would be a nice to have. current i'm using an inner join to filter down to another sheet with details

Comment: I agree, the hover text would be nice. Unfortunately I'm not aware of any way to do that right now. At Tableau Conference 2015 they showed a feature called Viz Within A Viz that allows you to embed detail worksheets into a hover tooltip but that's never made it into any release since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you want to treat latitude and longitude as continuous dimension for this worksheet instead of as a measure